# Path to Python Executable on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, heroku

I have an app the uses python shell module from Node.js to run a python script. Works on my local and everything. However when I run it on heroku the path to the python executable is throwing an error where it can't find Python.

I used `type -a python` on the Heroku console and it returned `/usr/bin/python` and `/app/.heroku/python/bin/python`

When I use either of these paths in the python shell `options[pythonPath]` object key, it doens't work and throws error `Error: spawn /app/.heroku/python/bin/python ENOENT`

I have the python and nodejs buildpack running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a config var under heroku app settings like,

```
PYTHONPATH = /usr/bin/python
```

then use it in your app by,

```
process.env.PYTHONPATH
```

where you need it

Hope this helps you